On polynomial growth rate of convolution of two sequences of non-negative integers
Let $\{a_n \}_{n\ge 0}$ and $\{b_n \}_{n\ge 0}$ be sequences of non-negative integers. Define a new sequence $\{c_n \}_{n\ge 0}$ as $c_n := \sum_{j=0}^n a_{j}b_{n-j}$. Let $t\ge 1$ be an integer such that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{c_n}{n^t}<\infty$. If $u,v$ are non-negative integers such that $u+v=t$, then is it true that either $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n^u}<\infty$ or $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{n^v}<\infty$ ?
Added: I am mainly interested in the case where $a_nb_n\neq 0$ for eventually all $n\gg 0$. Without this hypothesis, there is a counterexample as constructed by @Robert Israel in the answer below.
My thoughts: If the sequences $\{a_n \}_{n\ge 0}$ and $\{b_n \}_{n\ge 0}$ were both eventually $0$, then this would be true because then $c_n$ is just the coefficients of the product of the generating functions of $\{a_n \}_{n\ge 0}$ and $\{b_n \}_{n\ge 0}$, and hence we would be done by degree considerations of product of polynomials.

Let's construct a counterexample. I'll take $t = 2$, $u = v = 1$. To make $\limsup_n a_n/n = \limsup_n b_n/n = \infty$, I'll want increasing sequences of positive integers $M_k$ and $N_k$ and take $a_{M_k} = k M_k$, $b_{N_k} = k N_k$, and otherwise $a_n = 0$ and $b_n = 0$.
Now $c_n \ne 0$ iff $n = M_j + N_k$ for some $j$ and $k$.
We can choose the sequences $M_j$ and $N_k$ so there is  never more than one pair $(j,k)$ for any $n$: e.g. this is the case if $M_k$ is always a power of $4$ and $N_k$ is twice a power of $4$.
Now $c_{M_j + N_k} = j k M_j N_k$, and if we can make this $\le (M_j + N_k)^2$
we will have $c_n/n^2$ bounded above.  So take $N_k > k^2 M_k$ and $M_k > k^2 N_{k-1}$.

Very interesting! Is it possible to construct counterexample where $a_nb_n\neq 0$ for eventually all $n >>0$?

I have now added this information to my question

You can probably replace the $0$'s with $1$'s and get another counterexample.  It'll be a bit messier.

I see, I'll try to think about it. Btw, is there a counterexample with $t=1$? The reason I posed my question starting from $t\ge 1$, is because for $t=0$, I know my claim is affirmative. In view of your counterexample, I'm now wondering about $t=1$ ...
